# dynamically setting email adress in phpMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm having trouble when trying to set an email dynamically from a GET variable.
I've already tried converting to string, but I keep getting: "Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address."

```
$destinationEmail = $_GET["email"];

  //$destinationEmail = (string)$_GET["email"]; ----> already tried this.

function sendEmail($pdf,$data){

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "xxxxxx";
$mail->Password = "xxxx";
$mail->SetFrom("Noreply@email.com");
$mail->Subject = "Subject";
$mail->Body = "Hello";
$mail->AddAddress($destinationEmail);
$mail->addStringAttachment($pdf,"pdf.pdf");

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
}

if ( $_GET["email"] ){
    sendEmail($pdf,$data);
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you hard code the email like `$mail->AddAddress("hello@world.com");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sendEmail()` function doesn't know about the email address because that variable is out of scope. You need to pass the `$destinationEmail` variable to your `sendEmail()` function:

```
function sendEmail($pdf,$data,$destinationEmail){
 ...
}
```

And then add the email address to the function call:

```
if ( $_GET["email"] ){
    sendEmail($pdf,$data,$destinationEmail);
}
```

Comment: Also check the return value from `addAddress()` - it returns false if the address you supply is invalid (or empty), and you can use that to abort sending or display an error to the user.

Comment: gosh... I didn't see that. Thanks a lot